# How To Read A Particular Cell In Excel In Python And Make It A Variable

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am making a macro for minecraft, in the macro I want the module "pyautogui" to first press RIGHT CLICK then "2". But in my macro i want a custom input, And i don't want to annoy the user to death by learning and installing python. here is my code

```
import pyautogui
import keyboard
import time
import pandas as pd
# any other modules

# I need to define the  god damn excel
# need to read cell "B3"


# defining the click & wait function for ease of access
def click(amount):
    pyautogui.click(amount)


def wait(seconds):
    time.sleep(seconds)


# main
while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed("`"):
        click(1)
        wait(0.01)
        keyboard.press(2)
        wait(0.01)
        click(1)
```

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are trying to accomplish. You want to read something from excel, and then do what with it? Are you using excel as the input mechanism to your program, since you don't want users to input data in python?

Comment: i need python to take a cell, like "b3" and then take any text inside and store it in a string variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The module you're looking for is `xlrd`, alternatively you could use `openpyxl`. It loads the workbook, selects the sheet, and then you can get the value of the cell you want.

```
import xlrd

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('myfile.xls')
worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

value = worksheet.cell(row, column)
```